# Using SQL Server CONTEXT_INFO feature in ASP.Net + Enterprise Library (v5 & above)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, enterprise-library

I have a ASP.Net 3.5 web application with SQL 2008 as the back-end. I used ADO.Net's enterprise library Data Helper classes (Entlib 4.1) to access the DB and its stored procedures.

I initially set the `CONTEXT_INFO` in a stored procedure and then in subsequent stored procedures, I use the value set in `CONTEXT_INFO` to filter the queries. It worked perfectly in this setup.

I invoke the procedure to set `CONTEXT_INFO` from my C# code using the data helper classes and then call the other SP's which use the `CONTEXT_INFO`. Everything worked fine.

I then migrated to ASP.NET 4.5.1 framework with **EntLib 6** (tried with 5 also). I am facing a fundamental issue in that the `CONTEXT_INFO` value is not being retained between 2 subsequent SP calls. I have not closed the connection between calling the SP's/subsequent calls. Therefore none of my SP's return values.

### SP for setting CONTEXT_INFO

```
DECLARE @ContextInfo varbinary(128)  
SELECT @ContextInfo = cast( @SomeIDPassed AS varbinary(128) )

SET CONTEXT_INFO @ContextInfo
```

### Other SP using CONTEXT_INFO

```
(CONVERT(int, RTRIM(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(128), CONTEXT_INFO()),char(0), '')))))
```

Please provide your inputs.

Thanks,
Anand

```
 public class DataHelper:DataBase,IDisposable
  {

    public DataHelper() :
        base(AppDBConnString)
    {
        //If the user is logged in

            SetDBContextInfo(11);

    }


    private void SetDBContextInfo(int userId)
    {
        //Setting the User Context info for the SQL Server
        DbParameter[] parameter = new SqlParameter[1];

        parameter[0] = new SqlParameter("@userID", userId.ToString());
        parameter[0].DbType = DbType.String;
        parameter[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        ExecuteNonQuery("spSetContextInfo", parameter);
    }


     public virtual IDataReader ExecuteReader(String spName, DbParameter[]      dbParameters)
     {
        IDataReader reader = null;
        DbCommand dbCmd = BuildCommand(spName, dbParameters);
        if (transaction != null)
            reader = db.ExecuteReader(dbCmd, transaction);
        else
            reader = db.ExecuteReader(dbCmd);
        return reader;
     }

 }
```

The code which executes above mentioned method

```
DataHelper helper = new DataHelper();

DbParameter[] parameter = new SqlParameter[1];

parameter[0] = new SqlParameter("parameter0", "");
parameter[0].DbType = DbType.String;

drOrgGroupList = helper.ExecuteReader("MYProcedureName", parameter).AsSqlDataReader();
```

This doesn't return any data as `CONTEXT_INFO` is not retained.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because your code (the one that sets CONTEXT_INFO) needs to be run everytime a connection is open. Your subsequent database calls may be picking different connections from the connection pool. You need to make sure Enterprise Library (or whatever you may be using) runs the code immediately after the session is open.

Comment: I am calling the stored procedure that sets the CONTEXT_INFO first then i am immediately calling the other
stored procedures that uses CONTEXT_Info that was set earlier.
 

  This doesnt return any data as CONTEXT_INFO is not retained. I have added a Code Snippet to the original question above